# Extracting calendar .ics file from iPad backup

Tags: ios, backup, calendar, ipados

I used Finder on my Mac to back up an iPad (iPadOS 15) using USB-cable. Now I would like to get from that backup all the calendar events that are stored in a `*.ics` file. Is there a way to extract this soort of data from the local backup and without using iCloud services, [Apple data request](https://privacy.apple.com/) or third-party apps?

Comment: Does the .ics file already exist somewhere in the backup? You can experiment with the trial version of iExplorer to extract the file from the backup. I know this is a third-party app, but the trial version may do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

My copy of iMazing allows you to export calendar entries as .xls, .csv or .ics, readily.

I would guess, from that, calendar.app does not store calendar data in ICS natively. As ICS is a simple text file, and as such not a great way to store program data.

But like @IconDaemon indicated iExplorer (and iMazing) allow you to export calendar events without using iCloud.